# ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package in ONNX Library

Tags: python, nlp, huggingface-transformers, onnx

I am converting the T5 model from pytorch to ONNX using [this](https://github.com/onnx/models/blob/master/text/machine_comprehension/t5/dependencies/T5-export.py) script, but I am running into an Import module error. I don't think this a structural problem as this script has been used before by other people with no issues. Any ideas as to why I might be getting this error?

Here is the full error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:GitHub\models\text\machine_comprehension\t5\dependencies\T5-export.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import CombinedDecoder, SimplifiedT5Encoder
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: Here is the full error:```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:GitHub\models\text\machine_comprehension\t5\dependencies\T5-export.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .models import CombinedDecoder, SimplifiedT5Encoder
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package```